# Gnat compiler upgrade has led to an enum related Constraint_Error to appear

Tags: enums, ada

I am working on a legacy Ada 95 project inherited from another company. I have recently upgraded our compiler from Gnat 3.13a1 to Gnat 4.7.4. The program still compiles, but one of the tasks is crashing due to a Constraint_Error.

```
Process_Ua(Buffer, Msg_Kind);

Tr_Log5("MSG KIND IS: " & Message_Received_Type'Image(Msg_Kind));
```

The Constraint_Error occurs on the second line above, with the message "Invalid Data." Msg_Kind is of type Message_Received_Type (which is an enum type), and it is properly initialised at the start of this subprogram, so I'm having trouble understanding how the data could be invalid, when assigning anything that isn't of Message_Received_Type to Msg_Kind would result in a Constraint_Error when that occurs.

Comment: Try examining the value of `MsgKind`, or of `Message_Received_Type'Pos(Msg_Kind)`, just before the `Tr_Log5` call.

Comment: Not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but I've logged what you said using "Integer'Image( Message_Received_Type'Pos( Msg_Kind ) )". It's printing "32", but Message_Received_Type only has 6 possible values. How can this happen? This module has not been changed for the past 15 years, and only exhibits this problem with the new compiler.

Comment: Um, there's a bug in your program? Maybe the problem was there all along, and the problem was hidden because the older compiler failed to raise `Constraint_Error`. That's just speculation on my part. Do you still have access to the old compiler?

Comment: The problem could be uninitialized data.  You can't count on it to have any particular value, and changes in the way the code is generated (e.g. improved optimization) could affect the garbage value that is stored there.  If it has an invalid value, the language doesn't define what `'Pos` does with it, so 32 is a possible result.

Comment: @ajb, as I said, Msg_Kind is initialised at the start of the subprogram. Specifically, when it's declared.

I'm going to have to leave this for now anyway. It's been decided that due to the issues that are coming up, and the timeframes we have, we can't continue with getting it to work with the new compiler for now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Ogre I don't know what `Process_UA` is, but if this could set `Msg_Kind` (i.e `out` or `in out` parameter), the problem could be an uninitialized variable in `Process_UA`.

Answer (score 1):

`Invalid_Data` is always the sign of an uninitialized variable.

I presume you are compiling with `-gnatVa` and `pragma Initialize_Scalars` (which you have put in a `gnat.adc` file or in a file referenced from your project's `Builder'Global_Configuration_Pragmas` attribute).

In such a case, the compiler tries to initialize the variables with an invalid value (outside of the valid range), and adds additional checks. When the checks fail, they raise the `Invalid_Data` exception.

Perhaps the older compiler was always initializing an `out` parameter (but that would be surprising, how would it chose the default value) ?

Comment: "`Invalid_Data` is always the sign of an uninitialized variable." -- Always? It could be the result of an `Unchecked_Conversion` of an invalid value, or of having done something unsafe with checks suppressed.

Comment: Yes, it could also be an exception defined in your code. In my experience, though, when using `-gnatVa` and `Initialize_Scalars`, it is an uninitialized variable.